# Java postfix calculator

Tags: javascript, java, arrays

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CalculatorFinal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        float total = 0;
        int operator;
        float operand1, operand2;
        String WELCOME="Welcome to your Postfix Calculator\n====================\n";
        String[] StrArray;
        String  postfix  ="";


        System.out.print(WELCOME);



            System.out.println("Enter your postfix expression, OR to exit type stop:");
            StrArray = postfix.split(" ");

            for ( int i = 0; i < postfix.length();  i++) {





       // try {

             //Scanner myfile = new Scanner(new File ("postfix.txt"));
            // while (myfile.hasNext())
            // {
                // postfix = myfile.nextLine();
                // StrArray = postfix.split(" ");


                 if((postfix.length() > 3)  && (operand1 = floatvalueof(postfix[0]) && (operand2 = floatvalueof(postfix[1]) && (operator = floatvalueof(postfix[2])))))
                    {
                      try { // This deals with exceptions 

                            switch(operator){
                            case '+':
                            total = operand1 + operand2;
                            break;
                            }

                            switch(operator){
                            case '-':
                            total = operand1 + operand2;
                            break;
                            }

                            switch(operator){
                            case '/':
                            total = operand1 + operand2;
                            break;
                            }

                            switch(operator){
                            case '*':
                            total = operand1 + operand2;
                            break;
                            }


                      }
                        catch (NumberFormatException e) 
                            {
                            System.out.println("Error:- "+e.getMessage());
                            }








}}}}
```

I've been trying to make this postfix calculator work so that if someone types in 7 8 + the calculator will format it 7 + 8 and give the answer but i cant seem to do that. Any help  would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? "It doesn't work" is not a good question - be more specific. Also, nobody needs commented-out code. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sorry its the arrays part i dont understand it keeps coming up with errors. I'm trying to assign my values at the top to the arrays so in the first 2 arrays its the operands and in the last array its the operator e..g *,/. + or -

Answer (score 0):

There were a few things wrong with your code (or could be improved):

1. Variable names should be camel cased properly to improve readability
2. Assigning your operand and numbers are not really readable
3. You don't read the user's input at all
4. You have 4 different switch cases which handle one case each. The whole idea of switches are to put multiple cases (and a default handler) in 1 switch
5. You don't show the result of your calculation
6. You don't do anything when someone enters an unknown operator

I would strongly advise you to debug so you can see what your code is doing, line by line.

Here's an improved/fixed version of your code so it works and handles the above cases properly:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    Double result = 0D;

    System.out.print("Welcome to your Postfix Calculator\n====================\n");
    System.out.println("Enter your postfix expression, OR to exit type stop:");
    BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String input = bufferRead.readLine();
    if (input.toLowerCase().equals("stop"))
    {
      System.out.println("Received stop command.");
      return;
    }

    String[] inputArray = input.split(" ");
    if (inputArray.length == 3)
    {
      try
      {
        Double number1 = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[0]);
        Double number2 = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[1]);
        String operator = inputArray[2];

        switch (operator)
        {
          case "+":
            result = number1 + number2;
            break;

          case "-":
            result = number1 - number2;
            break;

          case "/":
            result = number1 / number2;
            break;

          case "*":
            result = number1 * number2;
            break;

          default:
            System.out.println("Received unsupported operator: " + operator);
            break;
        }
      }
      catch (NumberFormatException e)
      {
        System.err.println("Error:\n" + e.getMessage());
      }
    }
    else
    {
      System.err.println("Invalid number of arguments provided.");
    }

    System.out.println("Result: " + result);
  }
```